# Fixing Google Chrome text antialias for .ttf fonts

Tags: css, fonts, google-chrome

I have found [a topic](http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/font-face-chrome-rendering/) which presents a solution on how to get antialising working in Google Chrome - Windows, but they use `.svg` format. I have a `.ttf` format and I import all of my fonts like this at the moment:

```
@font-face {font-family: "t1"; src: url(../fonts/title/circle.ttf);}
@font-face {font-family: "t2"; src: url(../fonts/title/sanserifing.ttf);}
@font-face {font-family: "t3"; src: url(../fonts/title/serveroff.ttf);}
@font-face {font-family: "t4"; src: url(../fonts/title/pupcat.ttf);}
```

How can I achieve antialising done right in Google Chrome Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's a very bad idea just to provide TTF fonts since some systems and browsers use certain types. For maximum compatibility you should be using `.ttf`, `.otf`, `.eot`, `.woff` and `.svg` files.

A solution to this is to convert the TTF fonts to all the other formats, lucky enough this is a simple task and just a matter of visiting a website and converting the fonts. It's worth noting that some fonts have commercial licensing that does not allow you to use them on websites - ensure you check this to avoid any licensing issues.

To convert your TTF fonts visit [Font 2 Web](http://www.font2web.com/)

Comment: But how can i ichieve antialiasing?

Comment: convert your fonts and use url(‘webfont.svg#svgFontName’) format(‘svg’)or enable clear font type in windows.